# How to set intent filter for dial action in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a simple dial pad. I created all that and now I like to receive action dial intent from other applications.

```
<intent-filter>

       <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

       <data android:xxxxxx="XXXXXX" />

</intent-filter>
```

and now I don't know what should be filled with the data in action filter. 
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the intent filter should be used.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_DIAL" />                
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

And we can read the phone number from `onCreate` methord like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //start reading here
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getData()!=null){
            Log.d("intent received",intent.getData().toString());
            String phoneNumber = intent.getData().toString(); //contains tel:phone_no
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(4);
            Log.d("intent received","Received phone number : "+phoneNumber);
                  /// do what you like here
        }else{
            Log.d("intent received","null intent received");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is not working for me. After some search, I found this example from https://github.com/jdunck/Examples/blob/master/SimpleDialer/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".DialerActivity" android:label="@string/title_dialer">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: Anybody knows what is the difference between these actions?
DIAL, CALL_BUTTON, ACTION_DIAL?

Comment: DIAL = call a number from this activity,
CALL_BUTTON = ?,
ACTION_DIAL = This activity can receive intent if user call a number from any source. like contact app. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter> 

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
       <data android:scheme="tel" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

    </intent-filter>
```

in java

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:"  + edit_text_number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these intent filter -

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />                
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also the most important thing, to add permission -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Cheers :)

Comment: This is just near I want. But what i want is to open my application when click a number. for example when we press a mobile number from message.

Comment: you can use this code to call - 

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);

Comment: I like to receive Intent.ACTION_DIAL from other activities.